# weird facebook like button issue

Tags: facebook-like

The site: http://fraze.it

The issue: when connecting to the site via my PC I see 251 likes but when connecting 
via my IPAD I see 229. 
Both use the same connection. 
How comes the count value is different?

I will appreciate your thoughts.

thank you.

Comment: Probably a caching issue, but probably something you should ask Facebook, not us.

Answer (score 0):

There is something called a `CAP Theorem` in the database world. I suspect facebook to be a eventually consistent system. Thus even though the client connection is the same, its probable the servers serving the content are not the same. Thus you see the mismatch. Wait is all I can say, that is the only guarantee of an eventual consistent system.